# New unicode characters in C++0x

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11, char16-t, char32-t

I'm buiding an API that allows me to fetch strings in various encodings, including utf8, utf16, utf32 and wchar_t (that may be utf32 or utf16 according to OS).

1. New C++ standard had introduced new types `char16_t` and `char32_t` that do not have this sizeof ambiguity and should be used in future, so I would like to support them as well, but the question is, **would they interfere** with normal `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `wchar_t` types not allowing overload because they may refer to same type?

   ```
   class some_class {
   public:
       void set(std::string); // utf8 string
       void set(std::wstring); // wchar string utf16 or utf32 according
                                // to sizeof(wchar_t)
       void set(std::basic_string<uint16_t>)
                            // wchar independent utf16 string
       void set(std::basic_string<uint32_t>);
                            // wchar independent utf32 string

   #ifdef HAVE_NEW_UNICODE_CHARRECTERS
       void set(std::basic_string<char16_t>)
                            // new standard utf16 string
       void set(std::basic_string<char32_t>);
                            // new standard utf32 string
   #endif
   };
   ```

   So I can just write:

   ```
   foo.set(U"Some utf32 String");
   foo.set(u"Some utf16 string");
   ```
2. What are the typedef of `std::basic_string<char16_t>` and `std::basic_string<char32_t>` as there is today:

   ```
   typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring.
   ```

   I can't find any reference.

   Edit: according to headers of gcc-4.4, that introduced these new types:

   ```
   typedef basic_string<char16_t> u16string;
   typedef basic_string<char32_t> u32string;
   ```

   I just want to make sure that this is actual standard requirement and not gcc-ism.

Comment: You seem to have unintentionally reverted my trivial s/interfer/interfere/ spelling correction.

Comment: Thanks, merged your fix back.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1) `char16_t` and `char32_t` will be distinct new types, so overloading on them will be possible.

Quote from [ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N2018](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2018.html):

> Define `char16_t` to be a typedef to a
>   distinct new type, with the name
>   `_Char16_t` that has the same size and representation as `uint_least16_t`.
>   Likewise, define `char32_t` to be a
>   typedef to a distinct new type, with
>   the name `_Char32_t` that has the same
>   size and representation as
>   `uint_least32_t`.

Further explanation (from a devx.com article "[Prepare Yourself for the Unicode Revolution](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/34328/1954)"):

> You're probably wondering why the
>   `_Char16_t` and `_Char32_t` types and keywords are needed in the first place
>   when the typedefs `uint_least16_t` and
>   `uint_least32_t` are already available.
>   The main problem that the new types
>   solve is overloading. It's now
>   possible to overload functions that
>   take `_Char16_t` and `_Char32_t`
>   arguments, and create specializations
>   such as `std::basic_string<_Char16_t>`
>   that are distinct from
>   `std::basic_string <wchar_t>`.

2) `u16string` and `u32string` are indeed part of C++0x and not just GCC'isms, as they are mentioned in [various standard draft papers](http://www.google.com/search?q=u16string+site%3Aopen-std.org). They will be included in the new `<string>` header. Quote from the same article:

> The Standard Library will also provide
>   `_Char16_t` and `_Char32_t` typedefs, in analogy to the typedefs `wstring`,
>   `wcout`, etc., for the following standard classes:
>
> `filebuf, streambuf, streampos, streamoff, ios, istream, ostream, fstream, 
>    ifstream, ofstream, stringstream, istringstream, ostringstream,` **`string`**

Comment: According to the standard draft, `char16/32_t` are keywords, not typedefs. Who is right?

Comment: In gcc version 4.7.3, char16_t/char32_t are keywords.  I checked.  You can define a variable called `int32_t` (it's a typedef) but not `char32_t` (it's a keyword).